# How to mix regex and string in value.replace in OpenRefine / GoogleRefine?

Tags: regex, openrefine

I'm just trying to add "+33 " and remove the first "0" in a phone number like 04 35 73 84 93 (in France) to get +33 4 35 73 84 93 in a database of contacts where a field contains only the phone number.

I tried :
value.replace(/^'0'/,'+33 ')

There is no error, but the result is the same as the original.

I thought it would be very simple (I am a beginner with Open Refine), but it seems I am missing a bigger thing here!

Anyone can help? I searched quite a lot and this seems so simple that no one is speaking about it!

Comment: Take out the quotes around the `'0'`? The `//` are already a form of quoting; inside them the `'`s are taken literally I believe.

Comment: are you setting `value = value.replace(...)`? because most languages do not allow in place replacement for strings.

Comment: @JeffY is correct - the expression should be: value.replace(/^0/,'+33 ')

Comment: Thanks very much @JeffY and Owens, I've learned a new thing today!